# Write alias for columns with same names from multiple pivots in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My query is

```
SELECT *

FROM  (

WITH as1 AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.COMPANY_NAME,
    b.industry_sector,
    b.INDUSTRY_GROUP,
    c.VERTICAL,
    D.VCROUND,
    D.VCROUND AS VCROUND1,
    D.VCROUND AS VCROUND2,
    D.VCROUND AS VCROUND3,
    D.VCROUND AS VCROUND4,
    D.Deal_date,
    e.EMPLOYEE_COUNT ,
    a.REVENUE,
    a.TOTALRAISED ,
    D.Premoney_Valuation
FROM
    DAT.PIK.PB_C a
LEFT JOIN D.PIT.PB_COMPANY_INDUS b ON
    a.C_ID = b.C_ID
LEFT JOIN D.P.PB_COMPANY_V c ON
    c.C_ID = b.C_ID
    AND a.C_ID = c.C_ID
LEFT JOIN DA.PIT.PB_DEAL D ON
    D.C_ID = c.C_ID
    AND D.c_id = b.c_id
    AND D.C_ID = a.c_id
LEFT JOIN DA.PITCHBOOK.PB_COMP e ON
    e.C_ID = D.C_ID
    AND e.C_ID = c.C_ID
    AND e.C_ID = b.C_ID
    AND e.C_ID = a.C_ID
     where a.COMPANY_NAME ='11Sight'
                                
)
                                
SELECT
    *
FROM
    as1
    pivot(sum(TOTALRAISED) FOR VCROUND IN ('Angel', '1st Round', '2nd Round', '3rd Round', '4th Round', '5th Round')) AS p (
                                                                                                COMPANY_NAME,industry_sector,INDUSTRY_GROUP,VERTICAL,Angel_EmployeeCount,
                                                                                                R1_EmployeeCount,R2_EmployeeCount,R3_EmployeeCount,
                                                                                                R4_EmployeeCount,R5_EmployeeCount)
     pivot(sum(EMPLOYEE_COUNT) FOR VCROUND1 IN ('Angel', '1st Round', '2nd Round', '3rd Round', '4th Round', '5th Round')) 
     AS q 
    

     
    ).
```

I am getting 'Angel', '1st Round', '2nd Round', '3rd Round', '4th Round', '5th Round' , . Can you please tell me how to differentiate between columns from top pivot to bottom pivot which gives same columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so with this pared down SQL and fake_data:

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT *, VCROUND AS VCROUND1 FROM VALUES
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', 'Angel', 1, 1000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '1st Round', 10, 100000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '2nd Round', 11, 200000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '3rd Round', 12, 300000)
        v(COMPANY_NAME, industry_sector, INDUSTRY_GROUP, VERTICAL, VCROUND, EMPLOYEE_COUNT, TOTALRAISED)
)                            
SELECT *
FROM fake_data fd
    pivot(sum(TOTALRAISED) FOR VCROUND IN ('Angel', '1st Round', '2nd Round', '3rd Round')) AS p 
    (
        COMPANY_NAME,
        industry_sector,
        INDUSTRY_GROUP,
        VERTICAL,
        Angel_EmployeeCount,
        R1_EmployeeCount,
        R2_EmployeeCount,
        R3_EmployeeCount,
        R4_EmployeeCount,
        R5_EmployeeCount
    )
    pivot(sum(EMPLOYEE_COUNT) FOR VCROUND1 IN ('Angel', '1st Round', '2nd Round', '3rd Round')) 
     AS q ;
```

I get:

| COMPANY_NAME | INDUSTRY_SECTOR | INDUSTRY_GROUP | VERTICAL | "'Angel'" | "'1st Round'" | "'2nd Round'" | "'3rd Round'" | 'Angel' | '1st Round' | '2nd Round' | '3rd Round' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| comp1 | ind_1 | group_1 | virt_1 | 1,000 |  |  |  | 1 |  |  |  |
| comp1 | ind_1 | group_1 | virt_1 |  | 100,000 |  |  |  | 10 |  |  |
| comp1 | ind_1 | group_1 | virt_1 |  |  | 200,000 |  |  |  | 11 |  |
| comp1 | ind_1 | group_1 | virt_1 |  |  |  | 300,000 |  |  |  | 12 |

so agree it's confusing..

So moving away from PIVOT as it's not adding value, lets just write it by hand as:

```
WITH fake_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', 'Angel', 1, 1000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '1st Round', 10, 100000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '2nd Round', 11, 200000),
        ('comp1', 'ind_1', 'group_1', 'virt_1', '3rd Round', 12, 300000)
        v(company_name, industry_sector, industry_group, vertical, vcround, employee_count, totalraised)
)  
SELECT 
    company_name,
    industry_sector,
    industry_group,
    vertical,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='Angel', totalraised, null)) AS angel_totalraised,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='1st Round', totalraised, null)) AS r1_totalraised,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='2nd Round', totalraised, null)) AS r2_totalraised,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='3rd Round', totalraised, null)) AS r3_totalraised,

    SUM(IFF(vcround='Angel', EMPLOYEE_COUNT, null)) AS angel_employeecount,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='1st Round', EMPLOYEE_COUNT, null)) AS r1_employeecount,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='2nd Round', EMPLOYEE_COUNT, null)) AS r2_employeecount,
    SUM(IFF(vcround='3rd Round', EMPLOYEE_COUNT, null)) AS r3_employeecount
FROM fake_data
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

gives:

| COMPANY_NAME | INDUSTRY_SECTOR | INDUSTRY_GROUP | VERTICAL | "'Angel'" | "'1st Round'" | "'2nd Round'" | "'3rd Round'" | 'Angel' | '1st Round' | '2nd Round' | '3rd Round' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| comp1 | ind_1 | group_1 | virt_1 | 1,000 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 300,000 | 1 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

which is more of what I think you are looking for.